# Navigation bar images have space

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, spaces

I decided to change from my text/links to image links for my navigation bar, but now my images have spaces between them. http://justxp.x10.mx/test/
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your nav ul is an unordered list with no LI elements. Try fixing that for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `display` to `inline-block` on menu's links elements:

```
#navlinks a {
    display: inline-block;
    /* hack for old IEs */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
#navlinks a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: the "float: left;" being the important part